# DBpedia image links with CORS request problems

Tags: javascript, sparql

I have problems to display images retrieved from DBpedia links like "dbo:thumbnail" because of CORS request restrictions.
The image link at DBPedia that my Sparql query retrieves (in this example from `http://dbpedia.org/page/Sophie,_Countess_of_Wessex`) is `http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Special:FilePath/Sophie,_grevinna_av_Wessex.jpg?width=300`. This is not the final link to the image, it redirects to `https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/ab/Sophie%2C_grevinna_av_Wessex.jpg/300px-Sophie%2C_grevinna_av_Wessex.jpg` . My java script application wants to retrieve the image-url, is redirected and fails due to CORS request restrictions.
I can build a URL to the image page like `https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Sophie,_grevinna_av_Wessex.jpg` but that does not solve the problem since it only leads to the page of the image, not the image itself. The final image file url has a part in it that I do not understand - in the above example it is "a/ab" in the middle. This part seems to be random.
Is there any way to retrieve an image URL through a sparql query within a java script application and show the image on a canvas?

This is my Sparql query:

```
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbp: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
PREFIX dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX dct:  <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
PREFIX dbc: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX ex: <http://localhost:8890/ex/> 

CONSTRUCT
{?person rdfs:label ?name .
?person ex:icon ?picture_person_final .
?person dbo:title ?title .}

WHERE
{
SERVICE <http://dbpedia.org/sparql>
{
?person dbp:fullName ?name .
?person a dbo:Person .
?person dct:subject dbc:House_of_Windsor .
?person dbo:birthDate ?birthDate .
?person dbo:thumbnail ?picture_person .
BIND (strafter(str (?picture_person) , "http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Special:FilePath/" )AS ?picture_person_short1 )
BIND ( STRBEFORE(str (?picture_person_short1) , "?" )AS ?picture_person_short2 )
BIND(CONCAT ("https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:",(STR( ?picture_person_short2)))  AS ?picture_person_final )

FILTER (?birthDate > "1960-01-01"^^xsd:date)
?person dbo:title ?title .
}}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with the image urls? The urls work just fine for image tags: https://plnkr.co/edit/ZycIe9mbj6hQN7dUZv1z?p=preview

Comment: Your example works because it does not use an XHR request.
The problem comes with XHR (aka ajax) requests that pull data asynchronously. These need proper CORS request settings on the target machines which are impossible to get from wikipedia of course.